# is Pluggable authentication module a built-in module of modern linux/unix

Tags: linux, pam

How can I know that PAM is supported or built-in on our application supported OS, such as CentOS, Suse

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/pam.d/` directory contains the PAM configuration files for each PAM-aware application.